# Issue with Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tipcomments.asp?tip=1422) to create a calendar table, and am joining on cumulative week.  Here is the other query that I am running, but that gives me an inaccurate week by week count.  Does someone see where I erred?

```
--Creating table to house the data
CREATE TABLE Test
(
Count int,
name varchar(2000),
salesman varchar(100),
datesold DATETIME
)
--Inserting the data into the table
INSERT INTO Test(Count, name, salesman, datesold)
SELECT COUNT(ItemSold)
     , name
     , salesman
     , datesold
  FROM saleinfodatabase
 WHERE datesold IS NOT NULL
   AND item IN ('mink coat', 'persian rug')
   AND salesman IN ('Mike', 'Joe', 'Hale')
 GROUP BY 
       name
     , salesman
     , datesold


--Selecting data from the table
SELECT a.name
     , COUNT(a.Count) As Count, dt.CumulativeWeek 
  FROM Test a
 INNER JOIN 
       dim_Date dt
    ON a.datesold = dt.FullDate
 WHERE a.datesold IS NOT NULL
   AND a.salesman IN ('Mike', 'Joe', 'Hale')
 GROUP BY 
       dt.CumulativeWeek
     , a.name
```

Comment: You can take out the `WHERE` of the bottom `SELECT` since you already populated your table with that criteria.

Comment: Removing the extra where still causes inaccurate output

Comment: The `WHERE` is also not necessary because the `INNER JOIN` will never include records with a.datesold is `NULL`

Comment: Could yo show some data, and what result you are getting now? Because "result is wrong" does not give many clues...

Comment: Surely you want `SUM(a.Count)` not `COUNT(a.Count)` in your second query? Otherwise if you have, for example, 10 sales every day in a week your result will be 7, not 70 since you are just counting the data.

Comment: @GarethD You are correct, that is what my issue was.  I needed to use SUM!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gareth for giving me SUM instead of Count which was skewing my results